# Shiny R: Updating global environment objects from a batch file on a server application?

Tags: r, batch-file, rstudio

I have a shiny app that continuously runs on a server, but this app uses SQL data tables and needs to check for updates once a day. Right now, with no batch file in place, I have to manually stop the app, run an R script that checks for these updates, then re-run the app. The objects that I want to update are currently stored in RStudio's global environment. I've been looking around at modifying `.RData` files because I'm running out of options. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm aware that I probably have to shut down the app for a few minutes to refresh the tables, but is there a way I can do something like this using a batch file?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you are importing all of the data from SQL when the application starts, and then wanting a refresh every day.  This could be accomplished by loading your data into a reactive object and using `invalidateLater` set to refresh every 24 hours.

Comment: I have never heard of this, thanks for bringing it up! @Benjamin